# sort an array of custom objects by Double property value with Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, double

Im trying to move my self from objective-c to swift, I have a custom class named Market and this class contains some properties,

```
class Market  {
    var name = String?
    var volume = Double?
}
```

lots of them stored in an Array and im trying to sort this Array ascending or descending by the volume property.

I tried this but is not working, Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Double?' operands

```
self.market.sort(by:{$0.volume > $1.volume})
```

whats the most convenient swift-way to do this?

Comment: Why are the properties optional? Can you actually have a Market with no name or no volume?

Comment: i get the values from a json, there is a possibility that the api return nil to some of the properties, but i first do a loop with an optional binding and get all the objects that do have volume and market name and then trying to sort the new array i created

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `volume` is optional you can't compare the two value directly (except using `==`). So you need to decide what it means to compare one missing volume value against either another missing volume value or against a valid volume value.

If you want to keep it simple, you could treat a missing volume value as zero. Then you code becomes:

```
self.market.sort { ($0.volume ?? 0) > ($1.volume ?? 0) }
```

A more complicated version would always sort nil volume values at the end:

```
self.market.sort {
    if let v1 = $0.volume {
        if let v2 = $1.volume {
            // Both values exist
            return v1 > v2
        } else {
            // there is no v2 - treat v1 as < v2
            return false
        }
    } else {
        if let v2 = $1.volume {
            // there is no v1 - treat v2 as < v1
            return true
        } else {
            // both are nil
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Since `true` will be returned if `$0.volume` is `nil` regardless of the value of `$1.volume`, that can be reduced to:

```
self.market.sort {
    if let v1 = $0.volume {
        if let v2 = $1.volume {
            // Both values exist
            return v1 > v2
        } else {
            // there is no v2 - treat v1 as < v2
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Another option to consider is to avoid making your two properties optional. When parsing the JSON data, if either value is missing, simply skip that market since one could argue it isn't valid.

Comment: yes, thanks, its working, i remove all the nil objects values first after i get the json response

Comment: What do you mean that you "clear all the nil values first"?

Comment: sorry i edited my comment, i mean that i remove all the objects from the array that have nil on these 2  properties so i dont have to bother with nil values, the json has a lot of properties inside.

Comment: Then why make those two properties optional at all? Just avoid creating a `Market` instance if the JSON data is missing either value. Then you avoid all of the needless extra work of dealing with optionals when you will never actually have any markets with no name or no volume.

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible ways.

Use `??` operator but be sure with validation of the `volume`.

```
self.market.sorted(by: {$0.volume ?? 0.0 > $1.volume ?? 0.0})
```

Or use default value for the class property.

```
var volume: Double? = 0.0
```